# Java Jsoup iterate through drop downs and scrape dynamically added data

Tags: java, drop-down-menu, web-scraping, jsoup

Using JSoup and Java I want to get data that is added dynamically by selecting an option in a drop down list. An example that better shows what I am trying to articulate is http://www.bulletin.uga.edu/CoursesHome.aspx. Each dropdown option in the by prefix/major dropdown dynmically creates a dropdown that gives all the courses or an option that is "all courses". When you select a course it dynamically adds all the course info. If you select all courses it adds every courses data that is in that major.
I can get all the list values. Here is my code so far. I just dont know how to use the values to load all the data and iterate through it all.

```
package getInfo;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;


public class getInfo {

public static void main(String[] args){
    try{
    Document doc =    Jsoup.connect("http://www.bulletin.uga.edu/CoursesHome.aspx").get();
    org.jsoup.select.Elements links = doc.select("option");
    for(Element e: links)
    {
        //System.out.println(e);
        //System.out.println(e.text());
        System.out.println(e.attr("value"));
    }
    } catch (IOException ex){
        Logger.getLogger(getInfo.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
}
```

this returns a list of all the dropdown lists values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSoup is not the best bet here. JSoup is primarily an HTML parser. Although it offers some helpful methods for fetching content, it's not a headless browser.

I suggest you using Selenium here. It will handle easily dynamically added data.